# Trailing zeros omitted when inserting to postgres

Tags: postgresql, date, go

While inserting date with milliseconds part containing zero is skipping in PostgreSQL. If it have non-zero part in date, it will insert correctly into db.

eg: `2019-06-01 11:59:59:371Z` this will insert correctly into db but when I am inserting `'2010-06-21 11:59:59:010Z'` then will become `'2010-06-21 11:59:59:01Z'` last zero part is skipped.

I used a query

```
SELECT to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS:MSZ') 
FROM table_name;
```

then I will get data correctly but it is in string format and if i changed to time.Time format then zero part is skipped.

Is any method to forcefully store milliseconds without skipping zero to postgres or any method to resolve this issue

```
2099-06-21T23:59:59.371Z -> 2099-06-21T23:59:59.371Z
2099-06-21T23:59:59.000Z -> 2099-06-21T23:59:59Z
2099-06-21T23:59:59.010Z -> 2099-06-21T23:59:59.01Z
2010-06-21T23:59:59.001Z -> 2010-06-21T23:59:59.001Z
2010-06-21T23:59:59.100Z -> 2010-06-21T23:59:59.1Z
```

Comment: If `to_char()` displays it correctly, then value is stored correctly. So it must be something in the way you retrieve the value in your program that cuts off the milliseconds

Comment: yes , i am using golang so for convert this string to time.Time then it will skip zeros again from the result. i want this data in time.Time data type.i used
date := "2018-10-24T18:50:23.010Z"
parse_time, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, date)

Comment: It’s a presentation layer problem, not a database problem. Database stores it as a number and the zeroes in the end don’t matter. Why do you need it to have the zeroes?

Comment: the other ends expecting data with "2018-10-24T18:50:23.010Z" format.is any other method to solve this issue.

Comment: Then "the other end" expects a string value, not a timestamp value. And the solution to that, is to use `to_char()`

Comment: In Go are you scanning the query result directly into `time.Time` or are you scanning it into a `string` and then parsing it yourself? It might help if you update the question by adding you Go code.

Comment: scanning into time.Time directly but getting error so scanned to string and convert this string to time.Time format. then same problem occurred.

Comment: @aswathy What was the error when scanning into `time.Time`? And what was the type of the db value that you were trying to scan? What db driver are you using? For example if you are selecting a `timestamp` or `timestamptz` value from the postgres db, and you use the `github.com/lib/pq` driver, and you scan that value directly into `*time.Time`, then everything should work automatically, there should be no error, at least I know I've never got one.

Comment: datatype in psql is `timestamp with time zone` and i am scanning to struct contain `field_name          time.Time`. the driver used is github.com/lib/pq. the result of to_char(field_value, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS:MSZ') is a string so i can't directly scanned to `field_name          time.Time`

Comment: @aswathy Why are you using `to_char`? Why not just select the `timestamp with time zone` column and directly scan that to the `time.Time` field?

Comment: @aswathy if you something like this: `var t time.Time`, `err := db.QueryRow("SELECT now()").Scan(&t)`, do you get an error, or does it scan the value correctly? If it does work correctly is there a reason why you're not using this approach?

Comment: @aswathy note also that your "custom" formatting of the timestamp is considered invalid *input* even by postgres itself. See for yourself by running this query `SELECT to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS:MSZ')::timestamp;`. So there is no reason for the `lib/pq` driver to implement this specific format.

Comment: Stop messing with to_char, that's completely irrelevant. Scan from timestamptz into time.Time and use [Time.Format](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) if you want to output a specific format. See the example and pay attention to the two different ways to express fractional seconds (zeros vs. nines).

Answer (score 0):

Trailing zeros behind the decimal separator are irrelevant for the accuracy of a number.

If your application expects a certain fixed number of digits after the decimal separator, format the timestamp appropriately with the `to_char` function when you query the table.

If you want to avoid sprinkling your queries with `to_char`, define a view on the table that formats the timestamp as a string and use that view in your queries.

By all means, don't store timestamps as strings in a table. You would lose validity checks and date arithmetic, and you'd waste storage space.

Comment: I can use `to_char` in query. But it will return output with text format. then i used `to_timestamp` to convert string to time.Time format then zeros was skipping

Comment: You want the output as string, otherwise the trailing zeros would not be important.

Comment: I want output in time.Time format without skipping zeros

Comment: The zeros are not skipped, they are just not there. Internally, a timestamp is a number of microseconds starting at 2000-01-01 00:00:00. So if you want something else, you want the text format.